Sabre Not pulling certain rate codes hotel search
When making GetHotelAvailRQ along with rate code, we are getting 0775
Even though we made sure that property belongs to that rates.
HotelCode="100435430" CodeContext="GLOBAL"
<SearchCriteria SortBy="AverageNightlyRate" SortOrder="ASC" PageSize="40">
                <HotelRefs>
                    <HotelRef HotelCode="100435430" CodeContext="GLOBAL" />
                </HotelRefs>
                <RateInfoRef CurrencyCode="USD" BestOnly="3" ConvertedRateInfoOnly="false">
                    <StayDateTimeRange StartDate="2025-01-19" EndDate="2025-01-20" />
                    <Rooms>
                        <Room Index="1" Adults="2" Children="0" />
                    </Rooms>
                    <RatePlanCandidates ExactMatchOnly="true">
                        <RatePlanCandidate RatePlanCode="API" />
                        <RatePlanCandidate RatePlanCode="VMC" />
                    </RatePlanCandidates>
                    <RateSource>100</RateSource>
                </RateInfoRef>
                <ImageRef Type="MEDIUM" CategoryCode="1" />
            </SearchCriteria>

<ns11:ApplicationResults status="Complete">
                <ns11:Success timeStamp="2024-08-20T00:00:31.525-05:00" />
                <ns11:Warning timeStamp="2024-08-20T00:00:31.523-05:00" type="Application">
                    <ns11:SystemSpecificResults>
                        <ns11:Message code="WARN.0775">Nothing found for requested criteria</ns11:Message>
                        <ns11:Message code="WarningDetails">100-No rate available for requested ratecode and exactmatch is true</ns11:Message>
                    </ns11:SystemSpecificResults>
                </ns11:Warning>
            </ns11:ApplicationResults>

When do not send rate code, we get response but we made sure that it belongs to the rate code.
